# Why is my 3n+1 solution not working?

Tags: java, eclipse

My assignment for class is to write a method that Returns a string consisting of a Hailstone sequence beginning with the positive integer n and ending with 1. The string should consist of a sequence of numerals, with each numeral followed by a single space. When a numeral m (other than 1) appears in the sequence, it should be followed by nextHailstone(m). For example, nextHailstone(1) should return "1 " and nextHailstone(5) should return "5 16 8 4 2 1 ".

I have the following code and can't figure out why it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public static int nextHailstone (int n)
{
    if (n==1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    if (n%2 == 0)
    {
        return n/2;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((3*n)+1);
    }
}

public static String hailstones (int n)
{
    String result = "";
    result+=n;
    result+= ' ';

    while (true)
    {
        if (result.charAt(result.length()-2)=='1')
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result +=(nextHailstone(result.charAt(result.length()-2)) + ' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
public void testHailstones ()
{
    assertEquals("1 ", hailstones(1));
    assertEquals("16 8 4 2 1 ", hailstones(16));
    assertEquals("7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1 ", hailstones(7));
}
```

Comment: You get stuck in a loop because `if (result.charAt(result.length()-2)=='1')` is never true

Answer (score 1):

The reason your stuck in an infinite is that you have a while(true) loop. This will run infinitely unless broken. You never have the if statement true so it will continually run.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `result.charAt(result.length()-2)` to `nextHailstone`. This means you are passing a `char` and your `nextHailstone` operates on its `int` value, and not on the digit represented by that `char`. In addition, you only pass a single `char` to the `nextHailstone`. You don't handle multi-digit numbers.

For example, suppose you try `halstones (1)` :

You set `result` to "1 ". Then you pass '1' to `nextHailstone`. But the char '1' is `49` as `int`. So instead of returning `1` as you expect, it would return `49*3+1=148`. `result` would be updated to "1 148 ".

At the next step you'll pass the char '8' (ignoring the `14`) to `nextHailstone`, which is `56` as int. You can see why your loop will never terminate.

You should probably store the sequence in a `List` of `int`s, and only convert it to `String` when you are ready to return the output.

You can do something like this :

```
public static String hailstones (int n)
{
    List<Integer> seq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    seq.add(n);

    while (true)
    {
        if (seq.get(seq.size()-1)==1)
        {
            return seq.toString(); // You might have to change that if you require
                                   // the output in a different format
        }
        else
        {
            seq.add(nextHailstone(seq.get(seq.size()-1)));
        }
    }
}
```